# Service worker not returning a cached response, unless url contains a slash at the end

Tags: caching, service-worker, progressive-web-apps, service-worker-events

I have a SPA at `https://example.com/customer/app`.

When you visit that page, if you are not logged in, the SPA appends `#/login` to the url, so now it reads `https://example.com/customer/app#/login`.

There is a service worker running, installed with scope `/customer/app`.

I am trying to return a 200 response from my service worker when the app is offline. For simplicity's sake, I am using a dummy response for everything in my app at the moment:

customer-sw.js reads:

```
self.addEventListener('install', function(e) {
    // Do nothing for now.
});

self.addEventListener('fetch', function(event) {
    event.respondWith( new Response('Hello world') );
});
```

This means that every request should result in a simple `Hello world` (as if it was a page cached that way), if the service worker is installed correctly. Only problem is that I can't get this to work unless there is a slash at the end of the url, i.e. `/customer/app/` instead of `/customer/app`. A request to `/customer/app` results in retrieving the actual page, while a request to `/customer/app/` (or any other request below that) results in `Hello world`.

I figured I would post this question in case anyone else is stumped as to why they can't get their service worker to respond with a cached page. It seems the secret is to make sure you're using a slash at the end of your url. I wish [Google's documentation](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/offline/#7) would point out this little detail.

Nevertheless, out of curiosity, is there any way to get it to work with `/customer/app`? Right now it's looking like I'm going to need to redirect `/customer/app` to `/customer/app/` and test to make sure nothing is broken as a result.

Answer (score 1):

The default scope of the service worker is the path, where the script is.
`/customer/app` is treated as higher than `/customer/app/`.

You can change this behaviour and allow higher scopes with the `Service-Worker-Allowed` response header:

https://developers.google.com/web/ilt/pwa/introduction-to-service-worker#registration_and_scope

https://w3c.github.io/ServiceWorker/#service-worker-script-response

```
// Default scope:
// Maximum allowed scope defaults to the path the script sits in
// "/js/" in this example
navigator.serviceWorker.register("/js/sw.js").then(() => {
  console.log("Install succeeded with the default scope '/js/'.");
});


// Set the scope to an upper path of the script location
// Response included "Service-Worker-Allowed : /"
navigator.serviceWorker.register("/js/sw.js", { scope: "/" }).then(() => {
  console.log("Install succeeded as the max allowed scope was overriden to '/'.");
});
```